# Orchard's Context data - so close yet so far

Tags: orm, orchardcms, datacontext

Stepping thru the object hierarchy while debugging - starting from the WorkContext.CurrentUser viewed from debugger's Locals - all these properties have correctly populated values and I can access the values of 2 circled properties with:

```
WorkContext.CurrentUser.Email
WorkContext.CurrentUser.UserName
```

I'd like to understand the syntax that lets me access the value in `'InstitutionId'`
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the syntax in the Watch window if you right-click one of them and select Watch?

Comment: ((Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart)((((Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage<dynamic>)(this)).WorkContext).CurrentUser)).InstitutionId and if I paste that to the Command Window the correct value is returned. But I need to access the value in my View (where my breakpoint sits) Just pasting that value (preceded by '@') merely returns the string 'Orchard.Users.Models.UserPart.InstitutionId'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you altered the core `UserPartRecord` class (added `InstitutionId` property), but haven't altered the `UserPart` to expose it. `UserPart` is a wrapper around that record that exposes record properties.

You can always access the underlying record data directly like this:
`WorkContext.CurrentUser.As<UserPart>().Record.InstitutionId`